# count occurrences of list of substrings in pandas df col

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the occurrences of list of substrings in a column which contains a long string, and create a count column in the pandas df

```
      Input:          
     ID    History

     1     USA|UK|IND|DEN|MAL|SWE|AUS
     2     USA|UK|PAK|NOR
     3     NOR|NZE
     4     IND|PAK|NOR

       lst=['USA','IND','DEN']


     Output :
     ID    History                      Count

     1     USA|UK|IND|DEN|MAL|SWE|AUS    3
     2     USA|UK|PAK|NOR                1
     3     NOR|NZE                       0
     4     IND|PAK|NOR                   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lambda:

```
df.History.apply(lambda x: len([i for i in x.split("|") if i in lst]))
```

result

```
0    3
1    1
2    0
3    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way `str.count`

```
df1.History.str.count('|'.join(lst))
Out[316]: 
0    3
1    1
2    0
3    1
Name: History, dtype: int64

#df1['Count']= df1.History.str.count('|'.join(lst))
```